# Safari browser not pushing footer to the bottom of page for content greater than 100vh and having display flex

Tags: html, css

I am facing a weird issue using `flex` on Safari browser. The footer I am having inside a `flex` container is not going to the bottom when the page content is > `100vh`. Below is a format of my website structure. Please note that mine is a `Reactjs` app and I am using `styled-components` which handles all of the cross-browser CSS stuff, this is just a basic structure.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .root {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .page {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }

      .page_left {
        min-width: 100px;
        background: black;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .page_right {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .content {
        flex: 1;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }

      .content_left {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        background: yellow;
      }

      .content_right {
        min-width: 200px;
        background: orange;
      }

      .footer {
        min-height: 50px;
        background: blue;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="root">
      <div class="page">
        <div class="page_left"></div>
        <div class="page_right">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="content_left">
              <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
                text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br /><br /><br />
                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                <br /><br /><br />
                It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
                desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br /><br />
                Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader
                will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
                looking at its layout.<br /><br /><br /><br />
                The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
                here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use
                Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
                ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by
                accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
                text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br /><br /><br />
                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                <br /><br /><br />
                It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
                desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br /><br />
                Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader
                will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
                looking at its layout.<br /><br /><br /><br />
                The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
                here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use
                Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
                ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by
                accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                <br /><br /><br />
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
                text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
                of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br /><br /><br />
                It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                <br /><br /><br />
                It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
                sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
                desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br /><br />
                Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader
                will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
                looking at its layout.<br /><br /><br /><br />
                The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
                here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use
                Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
                ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                <br /><br /><br />
                Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by
                accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="content_right"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically it's the `content` class where everything is happening. Even it's set to `flex: 1`, it's only taking the `100vh` height and not the complete content height. If I change `display` to `block`, the footer does get pushed to the bottom. But I can't change the `display`property, it would break the complete app.

Here are the screenshots from chrome and safari for the same element(`content` class) which is causing the issue into my real app.
Safari(not working): [image: Safari]
Chrome(working fine): [image]

Edit: Here is the layout diagram
[image: layout]

Answer (score 0):

on the `#page` element, where you have the `display:flex` you can control the way things vertically align by using `align-items:`.

`align-items: flex-start` – aligns to the top
`align-items: flex-end`  – aligns to the bottom
`align-items: space-between` – justifies inside divs (applicable when there is more than one div)
`align-items: stretch` – stretches the elements within to all match in height.

You can also control the way elements are aligned horizontally with `justify-content:`.

Also, if you change the `flex-direction: row` then it will flip the `align-items` to control the horizontal alignment and the `justify-content` to control the vertical alignment.

CSS Tricks has a good read on Flex, though it is getting a bit old now, the basics are still great to read.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Otherwise, w3s has some articles that are bite-size and helpful.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

I hope that helps!

Comment: I am not sure how it answers the question. The `flex-direction` is by default `row`. The problem here is that on safari browser the `flex:1` is not working. It should take the complete content height but it's only taking `100vh` height of content.

Comment: Okay, I had it working with an align-items, but I actually think it is better to simplify the code altogether. There appears to be a lot of divs within divs, and there is no need for a height attribute on elements. Here is an example, the sidebar is going all the way down.  https://codepen.io/kellyannmcnamara2/pen/qBdwxox

Comment: but you changed the HTML. Here is a simplified version of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931915/flex1-taking-only-the-100vh-height-on-safari-browser-instead-of-full-content-he

Comment: In my first answer, I said to align-items: stretch;