# flex:1 taking only the 100vh height on safari browser instead of full content height

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having the below structure of html:
[image: Desired Layout]

```
<div class="root">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="page_left"></div>
    <div class="page_right">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content_left">
          <p>
            content here
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content_right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is fine except on Safari browser. The `content` is not taking the complete height of the `<p>` if the text inside is greater than 100vh. Even though it has been set to `flex:1` it only takes `100vh` height. But as per the CSS rules `flex:1` takes the complete height of the container. The container of `content` is `page_right` and it does the complete height of the content.  Don't know what the issue here.

```css
/* prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io (PostCSS: v7.0.26, autoprefixer: v9.7.3) */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.page .page_left {
  min-width: 100px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.page .page_right {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.page_right .content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.page_right .content .content_left {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
}

.page_right .content .content_right {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="page_left"></div>
    <div class="page_right">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content_left">
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br
            /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
            <br /><br /><br /> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br /><br
            /> Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.<br /><br /><br /><br /> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution
            of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
            <br /><br /><br /> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            <br /><br /><br /> Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
            <br /><br /><br /> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
            a type specimen book.<br /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
            <br /><br /><br /> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br /><br
            /> Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.<br /><br /><br /><br /> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution
            of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
            <br /><br /><br /> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            <br /><br /><br /> Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
            <br /><br /><br /> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
            a type specimen book.<br /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
            <br /><br /><br /> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<br /><br /><br
            /> Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.<br /><br /><br /><br /> The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution
            of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
            <br /><br /><br /> Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            <br /><br /><br /> Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="content_right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not: This is the structure of my real application, so probably I can't change the HTML.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/puspender/pen/gOpqXGW?editors=1100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this. And let me know if it helped.

**.page_right** only needs overflow auto, because inside of it you have only one element which is **.content**

```css
.page .page_right {
  /* -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column; */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**.content** I've added **min-height: 100%;** to set height for content of the whole page when we've not enough content. I've also removed width: 100% because by default content will take the whole space left

```css
.page_right .content {
  /* -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox; */
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**.content_left** this is optional, but I think in this div content may flow in default flow without flex.

```css
.page_right .content .content_left {
  /* -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex; */
  background: yellow;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.page .page_left {
  min-width: 100px;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.page .page_right {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.page_right .content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.page_right .content .content_left {
  background: yellow;
}

.page_right .content .content_right {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="page_left"></div>
    <div class="page_right">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content_left">
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br
            /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br
            /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

          </p>

          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br
            /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br
            /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

          </p>

          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br
            /><br /><br /> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

          </p>

        </div>
        <div class="content_right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did worked on the code here. Please mention what you did and why it changed the behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

You can try setting

```
.page {
  align-items: stretch; 
}
```

As `.page` is set to `flex-direction: row;` (default value), you have to use the property `align-items` to specify the behaviour of the elements in the **cross axis**.

Please check:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ (align-items section)

Comment: You should have tested your solution before posting it(mentioned in bounty).

Comment: I don't have access to any device with Safari. I thought I could give you something you could start with. Sorry about that.